# navigate back button don't work with saucelab android automation appium c#

Tags: c#, automation, appium, appium-android, saucelabs

On Saucelabs, I'm automating an application for an Android smartphone with Appium. I was attempting to access the device's navigation buttons; I wanted to do a back operation (just hit the back nav button), so I utilized `TouchActions` and attempted `Driver.navigate.back()` but it was not working.

Using

```
Appium: 2.0.0
Android: 14.0
Device: Pixel *
Type: Emulator
```